# Permutation of a numbers in array to sum a number

Tags: algorithm

I have given an array.And i want to find the all permutation of an array so it sum to a specific numbers.
Example
`Array a =[2,3,5 ,1]`
 Target = 8
`Solution: [2,2,2,2] ,[5,3] ,[3,3,2] ,[5,2,1] and all possible combination
Please provide me a approach to solve this  the problem , the problem i am facing how to handle the repetition of the elements.Target is a large number of 10^6.
I think it is same as[This theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29)

Comment: This is sometimes called the coin changing problem and is a standard algorithms question. You may have more luck searching for that term.

Comment: Thanks all of you i have found that it is a standard algorithm will be posting my solution soon

Comment: What about `[5,1,1,1]`, `[3,3,1,1]`, `[3,2,1,1,1]` and `[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]`, and [many more]?

Comment: @tobias_k please go through [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-7-coin-change/)

Comment: No thanks. Why don't you just explain in your question why it's okay to have 4x2 but not 8x1 or 2x3+2x1?

Comment: @tobias_k ya it was my mistake i realized that thanks for pointing out

Comment: a little help what if the order matter i.e [2,3] and [3,2] are different

Answer (score 1):

You are facing a typical [Subset Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem). The worst case complexity of this problem is exponential no matter how you put it. You might find good polynomial-time approximations that work wonders for average case though.